# Microsoft Power apps file upload to shared folder

Tags: powerapps

My user wants a PowerApp application in which they will attach a file from their local machine and then they will Upload the file and that should be uploaded to some network drive.

Looking for a suggestion.

Comment: There is a connector available in the Power Automate file **network drive**